# How to pass trigger parameters to notebook in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, databricks

In Databrick Notebook, I would like to know which file trigerred pipeline.

I have prepared Azure Data Factory pipeline. It got blob event based trigger and It runs databricks notebook.
In databricks notebook I would like to know which file trigerred pipeline[its path as well]

Trigger itself works, as it triggers when i upload a file.

I have prepared pipeline parameters of type string and values like
SourceFile    string  @triggerBody().fileName
SourceFolder  string  @trigger().outputs.body.folderPath

In task i have prepared parameters like:
SourceFile    @pipeline().parameters.SourceFile
SourceFolder  @pipeline().parameters.SourceFolder

In Databricks Notebook such a code:

```
dbutils.widgets.text("SourceFolder", "","")
y = dbutils.widgets.get('SourceFolder')
print ("Param -\'SourceFolder':")
print (y)
```

prints this:

Param -'SourceFolder':
@trigger().outputs.body.folderPath

I would like to see path or file name not command.

Comment: what error you are facing and what your output for the above?

Comment: Everything described. There is no error. Command which is meant to give file name according to Azure docs is printed, instead of return value. I would like to have file name in Databricks notebook, not command

Answer (score 3):

I tried the above in my environment and it is working fine for me.

I created two parameters `foldername` and `filename`.

I have created the trigger like below.

[image]

Give the trigger parameters `@triggerBody().folderPath` and `@triggerBody().fileName` to the pipeline parameters like below.

[image]

Then I have created a set variable to create the file path with below dynamic content.

`@concat(pipeline().parameters.foldername,'/',pipeline().parameters.filename)`

[image]

Pass this as Notebook base parameter.

[image]

**Notebook Execution:**

[image]

Also, I tried with `@trigger().outputs.body.fileName` and `@trigger().outputs.body.folderPath` and it is working fine for me.

First try with a set variable and see if you are getting the file path from trigger parameters.

If still, it is giving the same, then it's better to raise a [Support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) for your issue.

Comment: Thank you for this. What i have done wrong was to fill pipeline parameter with function. I should have done it on trigger level. So i have cleared values for pipeline parameters and edited trigger

Comment: yeah, we should give the values on trigger level, only then the trigger parameter's value will be assigned to pipeline parameters.