# If one of the file is updated my job should run in databricks for this condition which activity should i use?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My model is taking input from 5 file. If one of them updated or uploaded my model should run through ADF.
Here sales_target is my model depend on 5 files. I was trying to use **GetMetaData Activity**
and pass **LastModifiedDate** as a FieldList. But that one will not work.
[image]

Can you pls help me on this

Comment: Can you provide your pipeline structure for better understanding? also any blockers that you are facing?

Comment: i am not able to think which activity should i use in this cobdition?

Comment: where your source files exists? a storage account?

Comment: yes in storage accounts

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your requirement, you can use **[Storage event triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger?tabs=data-factory#create-a-trigger-with-ui)** in ADF  which triggers the ADF pipeline whenever any new file added or any file modified.

But for this method, the folder in storage account which contains the required files must not have any extra files other than the required files. It means, the folder should be dedicated to this job only.

Create a storage event trigger in ADF and attach it to the pipeline.

[image]

Give the container name, folder name for the **Blob path begins with** and based on your file extension, you can give **Blob path ends with** like above.

Here, I have one file in the specified location, and we can see it while creating the trigger.

[image]

If you want to get modified file name or file path, you can get those using trigger parameters. Go through this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75518302/how-to-pass-trigger-parameters-to-notebook-in-azure-data-factory/75519911#75519911) to understand about it.

After creating the trigger, use a web activity to execute the databricks job.

Use [REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/jobs/runnow) to execute the databricks job.

```
https://<databricks instance>/api/2.1/jobs/run-now
```

Pass the desired job id through web activity body and use databricks PAT token as Bearer token authentication.

Make sure you publish the pipeline and trigger before starting your task.

Here, I have modified some content in my file in storage account and you can see the pipeline was triggered.

[image]

The databricks job also executed from the ADF web activity.

[image]

If you want to execute notebook code instead of databricks job, you can use Notebook activity in ADF.